# jQuery UI slider min/max values to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble with variable scopes understanding so it's kinda hard for me to fix this. I have js script which looks like that:

```
<div id="slider"></div>


$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){

  var update = function() {
    var min = $("#slider").slider("values")[0];
    var max = $("#slider").slider("values")[1];

     var i = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Hi");
    }, min + Math.random() * max);

    return i;
  }

  var i;

  $("#slider").slider({
    values: [1000, 1750],
    min: 500,
    max: 3900,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
      clearInterval(i);
      i = update();
    }

  });

});

});
```

How do I actually make min and max variables "global" that I can use them out of this function or somewhere else? interval with console.log can be an example, don't worry. Generally, this is a slider from jQuery UI.

Comment: Define them after document ready : 

`$(document).ready(function() { //your variables goes here` 

Try it and write a reply.

Comment: As I said am totally noob with these scopes understanding, am working on it, but I am not good on it so far. As you said, I've tried it but got the output of NaN. So if you could give me some example that would be good tho.

Comment: Add hidden fields into your html and update them by using your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the min and max variables within a function, they are only available within that function.  However, if you declare them in the global scope (outside any function), you can access them from anywhere.

When updating a global variable from within a function, do not use the `var` keyword:

```
myVariable = myValue;  // without var keyword, this variable refers to global myVariable (or wherever it is first found in the scope chain.  If not found, it will create a new variable in current scope.)
```

If you use the `var` keyword, a new variable will be created in the current scope.

```
var myVariable = myValue;  // this creates a new variable myVariable in the current scope
```

```js
// Declare variables in the global scope
var min = 50;
var max = 200;

var update = function() {
    // Update the global variable - do not use var keyword
    min = $("#slider").slider("values")[0];
    max = $("#slider").slider("values")[1];
}

// Logs the global min/max variables
var logValues = function() {
    console.log("Min = " + min + ", Max = " + max);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){

  $("#slider").slider({
    values: [50, 200],
    min: 5,
    max: 390,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
      update();
    }
    
  });
  
});

});
```

```css
input { display: block; margin: 20px 0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<p>Moving the slider updates min and max variables to the current selected values.</p><p>  Click the button to log the current value (taken from global variables).
<input type="button" value="Get Current Values" onclick="logValues()" />
```

Comment: Thanks once again, but when I'm trying to move the console.log above, where min and max values are declared I am getting undefined output. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, because at that point min and max are only declared, but they don't have any value yet.  I will update the code, and initialize these variables to the initial values.

Comment: I've updated the answer to demonstrate how you can use the variables in the global scope.

Comment: My last question is, how do I update the variable "live" that I don't need to press that button for changing it? I mean I want to have it updated no matter if I move the slider or not. :)

Comment: The variable is updated "live" whenever you move the slider.  You don't have to press the button to update the variable, pressing the button just logs the values to the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149427/discussion-between-chava-g-and-hatchling).